Can the Joby eVTOL be used in FS2024's career mode for SAR missions?
I know the following from skipping through some livestreams:

Microsoft Flight Simulator 2024 has a career mode
that career mode has Search and Rescue Missions
I believe those missions are divided into two categories: rotorcraft and airplanes (fixed wing?)
aircraft selection for those missions might be restricted? But I don't understand how/if that selection changes

So my question:  can the Joby eVTOL in particular be used for search and rescue missions in Microsoft Flight Simulator?
(If there's some straightforward mod that allows it I am interested in that as well.)

apologies for improperly using the microsoft-flight-simulator tag, which I think is for FS2020 only.  I didn't see a tag for FS2024 and don't have enough rep from my older random DCS Q+A to create a tag myself.

No worries, now it's fixed
